# Sequences of numbers. Forecasting

Tags: python, statistics

I have a big statistical sampling of sequences of numbers:

```
[13, 11, 21, 14, 16],
[23, 14, 16, 11],
[21, 13, 15, 14, 24, 17, 14, 11, 7, 18],
...
```

Each value in sequence means wait time in a queue. Sequences have different lengths.

I want to predict wait times in new queues based on statistics.

For example, first values in new queue are 12, 14, 13, 15. I want to predict next wait times.

Which algorithm can I use to solve this problem in python? May be neural networks? Then which type of neural network can solve it?

Or may be I have to build a regression function? But my sequences have different sizes and I want to get several numbers in new queue.

Comment: how are you going to predict a unknown sequence of numbers? the length of the sequence should probably be determined first

Comment: You start with simple n-gram-models

Comment: Of course for new queue I have the fixed length. For example, 10 values. And I want to predict them.

Comment: First you need to choose the statistical forecasting method you'd like to use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forecasting. Then python might come into the picture to implement that.